# How to get the total numbers of rows stored in the MySQL database table?

Tags: mysql

Is there a MySQL command to count the number of rows in a table, and if so, what is it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

MySQL [COUNT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html) function

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table
```

Answer (score 5):

A nice way to get AN ESTIMATE of the number of rows can be via meta-data information in the information_schema tables.

Note, this is just an ESTIMATE used for query optimizations.

There may be a way to get exact # of rows from the information_schema, but I am not 100% sure if this is possible.

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name, table_rows
FROM information_schema.tables
ORDER BY table_rows DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the number of rows from a specific table name that you set:

```
SELECT TABLE_ROWS from information_schema.TABLES where table_name = "your_specific_table_name_here";
```